# Swap array keys with inner object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have this array which holds objects;

```
let arr = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "level": "2",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "level": "3",
    }
]
```

By default the array has keys starting from 0 and it looks like this:

```
[
    0: {id: 1, level:2},
    1: {id: 2, level:3}
]
```

How can I transform it so that the keys are the values of the property 'level'?
It should look like this:

```
[
    2: {id:1, level:2},
    3: {id:1, level:3}
]
```

So far I have tried this but it doesn't remove the original keys:

```
arr.map((v, k) => ({[v.level]: v}));
```

So I have something like this:

```
[
    0: {2:
        {id: 1, level:2}
    },
    1: {3:
        {id: 2, level:3}
    }
]
```

Comment: `arr.map((v, k) => ({[v.level]: v}));` your code should give the result

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath It doesn't.

Comment: The result you're expecting is impossible, you need an object, not an array. 
`{ 2: { id: 1, level: 2 }, 3: {id: 2, level: 3 } }`

Comment: @Petyor put it in snippet in the question, you will see your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate a new array using reduce:

```
arr.reduce((prev, curr) => { prev[curr.level] = curr; return prev }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I prefer the `reduce` method, but you could also construct an "array-like" (i.e. an `object` with numeric keys and a `length` property) and pass it to `Array.from`

```
const maxIdx = Math.max(...arr.map(v => parseInt(v.level, 10)))
const arrLen = maxIdx + 1;
const arrayLike = { 
    ...Object.fromEntries(arr.map(v => [v.level, v])), 
    length: arrLen
};
const mappedArray = Array.from(arrayLike);
```

For output of

```
[undefined, undefined, {
  "id": 1,
  "level": "2"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "level": "3"
}]
```